# android image scaling methods for very large images;

Tags: android, android-image

I have image on server of dimension 1000x800. I download it using following approaches:

1. download full image , put the pixel values in array decode a bitmap from it and scale it.
2. download parts of image , put them on canvas and scale the canvas.

Which approach is better regards to memory issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be:

3) Downsample/scale the image without decoding it

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

  // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
  final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

  // Calculate inSampleSize
  options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

  // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
  return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

It is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). The sample code is from there too.